# cache: [GET /] miss? dalli gem, memcached, rails 3.1, nginx, unicorn production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

I'm struggling to get a first application running in production. No matter what I do I get a basic 404 page and this in my unicorn log, no matter what I do:

> ```
> cache: [GET /] miss
> cache: [GET /something] miss
> ```

production.rb

> ```
>  config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211'
>  #config.cache_store = :memory_store
> ```

Everything worked fine in development (sans the caching which was skipped in development afaik), and doublechecking I have all the syntax correct as per rails guides for setting up controller action caching, only nothing but error messages.

Can anyone give some pointers on perhaps why or what I'm missing? Works in development, but not on the server I set up. I'm more than happy providing more info for getting this sorted out. This is a lot moving parts to coordinate, I'd appreciate any input.

edit:

I went in for some feedback from memcached, running it with all previous options and -B binary (plus -vv) it seems that the program doesn't even connect with memcached; memcached registers nothing while the program is running.

edit:

I went back to a local setup in development and production; caching works, memcached responds, the only difference is I'm not running through nginx/unicorn just webrick, but if that helps to pinpoint an issue I'm to be aware of perhaps that is of some use and a direction to pursue.

edit:

Going back to the server, and then running in development mode with cache configurations enabled:

> config.cache_classes = true
>   config.action_controller.perform_caching =
>   true config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1:11211'

It is obvious that rails is not connecting with memcached. There is nothing in the log about even attempting to connect with the cache, and memcache run with -vv shows no activity. If I go to the console I can manually connect as per the dalli basic cli instructions, hmmm. Just trying various options with memcached instances yields no response.

However, I can query memcached stats on an index page that comes up on each request where I've set it...though showing nothing in the rails log about accessing memcached.

edit:

wrestled through this, and found the error was unrelated....once I sorted through some asset pipeline issues for a misreferenced style sheet, everything seems to be running smoothly. A learning experience, at least.

Comment: Any particulars of what the problem was, for those of us with the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dalli is binary protocol only, so make sure your memcached server speaks binary protocol. For example, memcached should be started with:

```
memcached [...] -B auto [...]
```

Also, the [memcached version must be >= 1.4.0](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes140).

**UPDATE**

These messages are generated by [Rack::Cache](https://github.com/rtomayko/rack-cache) being set to verbose logging mode and don't mean that anything is necessarily wrong. They're more of a reminder that you could do stuff like

```
expires_in 20.minutes
expires_in 3.hours, :public => true
expires_in 3.hours, 'max-stale' => 5.hours, :public => true
```

(in your Rails controllers) and then page caching may automagically work (and these messages would go away any time a page is rendered from the cache).

Comment: It is 1.4.5....and it starts with the default which is autonegotiate, I just pulled it through apt on ubuntu and it configured itself to start with server boot.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, turned into another problem, but this did cue me to a better understanding of integrating memcached and rails

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rails.cache.read('[key]')` via heroku console to discover if it is working or not